# Фразеологізм антонім до фразеологізму "ґедзь напав"

Tags: фразеологізми, антоніми

Часто чую вживання фразеологізму "ґедзь напав".

Значення фразеологізму із [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=17975&page=700)

> **ґедзь (ґедз) напа́в (укуси́в)** / рідко **напада́в** *на кого, кого, несхв.* – у когось поганий настрій, хтось перебуває в неврівноваженому
> стані, нервує, сердитий і т. ін

Цікавить чи є до даного фразеологізму антонім-фразеологізм?

Comment: А яке значення могло б бути у фразеологізму-антоніма?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можу запропонувати такі варіанти:

[Розгоднилося на серці](https://dovidka.biz.ua/frazeologizmi-na-literu-r/) - у кого-небудь з’явився гарний настрій; комусь стало радісно.

[Пити радість](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=24&t=442) - перебувати в піднесеному настрої, схвильованому стані від чогось радісного.

Душа (серце) радується (співає) - відчувати велику радість.

Не чути землі (ніг) під собою.

Як (мов, наче, ніби і т. ін.) на світ народитися - бути дуже задоволеним, щасливим.

Ходити іменинником (як іменинник).

На сьомому небі (бути, перебувати і т. ін.).

Відчувати (ночувати) себе на небі.

Сапівати від щастя; аж танцює.